# Why I can't access to the Count property after a .ToList()

Tags: linq, list, ienumerable

I have this code :

```
var numbers = new []{ 1,2,3 };
IEnumerable<int> evenNumbers = numbers.Where(i=> i % 2 == 0);
```

now I turn this "collection" into a List :

```
evenNumbers = evenNumbers.ToList();
```

why now I can do only `evenNumbers.Count()` and not `evenNumbers.Count`?

With :

```
IList<int> evenNumbers = numbers.Where(i=> i % 2 == 0).ToList();
```

I can. Wont' `evenNumbers = evenNumbers.ToList();` materialize IEnumerable into a List?

Answer (score 1):

To your compiler, evenNumbers is still of the type IEnumerable. Your compiler has no idea that it's actually a List. The type of your variable, 'evenNumbers' doesn't change if you assign an object of a derived type to it.

Comment: So, it become a List but I can't use it as a List? :O

Comment: @markzzz Let's do an extreme example: `object o = evenNumbers.ToList()`; Do you think you could do `o.Count` or `o.Count()`? No, because the C# compiler doesn't know what is in the `o` object, and C# is statically linked (ignoring the C# 4.0 `dynamic` object)

Comment: Is it correct to say "a sort of cast at run-time"? Lol. Did you have any tutorial about this behaviour?

Comment: @markzzz This is standard Object Oriented behaviour. If you're not entirely familiar yet with the principles of OOP, I suggest, as a tutorial, you read an introductory book on the subject. Head First (from O'Reilly) has some excellent books with excellent examples. These books read (and sort of look) like a comic book, so it never becomes heavy literature.

Answer (score 1):

`evenNumbers` variable is still `IEnumerable<int>` after the assignment. You should create a new variable type of `IList<int>` or `List<int>` to use `Count` property since it's defined in the `IList<T>` interface. That's what you do in your second assignment.